# how to cut and copy to register multi line match a pattern using vim global command(g:)

Tags: vim, neovim

I know
Delete all lines matching a pattern.

```
:g/pattern/d
```

and yank to register (Copy all lines matching a pattern to register 'a'.)

```
qaq:g/pattern/y A
```

is there a command combine two command? (cut and copy to register in one command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as that

```
qaq:g/pattern/d A
```

Answer (score 0):

You may chain `y` and `d` with `|`:

```
:g/pattern/y A|d _
```